# Arduino: for/while/if before void setup() or void loop()? -- error: expected unqualified-id before

Tags: c++, arduino

Why does this not work?

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++){ 
  // Do stuff
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

In my concrete situation I want to initialize an Array of objects with parameterized constructors as shown here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-initialize-array-of-objects-with-parameterized-constructors-in-c/

My code snipped is:

```
MoistSensor* moistsensors = (MoistSensor*)malloc(sizeof(MoistSensor) * cfg.NumberOfMoistsensors);
for(int it=0; it < cfg.NumberOfMoistsensors; it++) {
    moistsensors[it] = MoistSensor(cfg.sensorPins[it], cfg.OnPWM, cfg.OffPWM, cfg.analogInPin);
}
```

with the Moistsensor Class being the one I want to generate objects of and cfg being an object that holds configuration data.

Comment: It's not completely clear but looks to me that you're trying to write code outside of a function. Don't do that, put your code inside of a function.

Comment: As an aside, there's very rarely (never?) any need for `malloc` in c++.  Instead use something like `std::vector<MoistSensor>`.

Comment: I've seen some bad code on geeks for geeks but that page you linked has to be the worst. That technique for `malloc` and 'parameterized constructors' is invalid C++. There actually are techniques for doing this that work, but not like that.

Comment: @G.M. I believe the issue is arduino. The STL is not usable on that platform.

Comment: @john Sorry, I missed the `arduino` tag.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Added Arduino to the title to make this more clear.

Comment: If you want to program that part using the bloated and wasteful Arduino code, then you have to follow the design paradigm. Code must be in a function and somehow that function must be called from either setup (an abstraction) or loop (another abstraction).

Comment: Code must be in a function for any C++ program.  That's not special for Arduino.  And if you don't like setup and loop, then write main yourself.  That works just fine.  Just be sure you remember to initialize all the hardware yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You want to move the initialization code into the `setup` function, like this:

```cpp
MoistSensor* moistsensors = nullptr;

void setup() {
  moistsensors = (MoistSensor*)malloc(sizeof(MoistSensor) * cfg.NumberOfMoistsensors);
  for(int it=0; it < cfg.NumberOfMoistsensors; it++) {
    moistsensors[it] = MoistSensor(cfg.sensorPins[it], cfg.OnPWM, cfg.OffPWM, cfg.analogInPin);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Code that needs to be executed has to be written in some sort of a function.
In C/C++ it is the `main()` function.

Whatever is outside any function can only be `declarations`, `functions`, `preprocessor directives`, etc; but NOT executable code.

In Arduino IDE, code that gets executed is written in two functions:

`void setup()` and `void loop()`

Code in `void setup()` will get executed only once during the program execution.

Code in `void loop()` is equivalent to code written in a `while(true)` loop

So except for `initialization of variables`, `function definitions`, `function declarations` and a few more things, everything else like `for` loops MUST be written in one of these functions